# Laravel 4 Url Helper functions not matching protocol

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I had read somewhere the the Laravel helper functions `route()` and `url()` would match the protocol of the current page. This has not been my experience and I cannot find a way to do it cleanly.

```
<!-- https://domain.com/public/route1 -->

<a href='{{ route('route2') }}'> domain.com/route2 </a>
404 due to lack of "/public/" and no https

<a href='{{ url('/route2') }}'> domain.com/public/route2 </a>
proper path but still drops https

<a href='{{ secure_url('/route2') }}> https://domain.com/public/route2 </a>
proper path and protocol but is explicit
```

Is there a way to do what I want? It seems absurd to me that these helpers would be unable to accomplish something this simple. Something that the following line of code does with no tricks (its downside being the obvious loss of benefits associated with using helper functions [UPDATE: in particular having everything break when running locally due to a different app path]):

```
<a href='/public/route2'> https://domain.com/public/route2 </a>
```

To further convolute things I would like to add that when running on localhost, the first version `{{ route('route2') }}` produces a path that includes `/public/`, though it is possible that I have a different config file somewhere on the server (this is a very large project). Bonus points if someone can point me in the right direction for that issue as well.

routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'route2' ), function(){
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'route2',
        function(){
            return View::make('pages.route2');
        }
    ));
    ...
});
```

Thank you kind souls!

UPDATE:

I have continued searching and been unable to find any relevant information regarding Helper function url generation. It seems the majority of info with similar keywords is about forcing HTTPS site-wide (server config) or setting up redirects. It just seems so much simpler to generate the correct link in the first place. Plain HTML can do it, so should Laravel.

UPDATE 2:

Using the asset helper seems to work how I would expect url to. Please someone tell me this hack is not my only option...

Comment: `route('route2')` will take you to a named route. Are you sure you have named a route already?

Comment: yes in the snippet of routes.php included, "/route2" should match the get and is named with `'as' => 'route2'`. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-prefixing

Comment: In Laravel 5, you need to set the third parameter of `url()` to true, I believe (and the second can be e.g. an empty array). Maybe it's the same in L4?

Comment: setting third parameter to true does indeed generate an https url, but again this is explicit and breaks local dev (no ssl set up). What I am asking is if there is a way to generate URL's with Laravel helpers the have the same protocol as the current page (like the simple HTML example I provided).